# Why do areas in Chrome not have a width?

Tags: jquery, html, image, google-chrome, imagemap

I have a peculiar use-case where I need to get the width and height of an , as well as it's offset.

On IE11, it works as expected, i.e. I can do

```
$("area:eq(1)").offset().left;
$("area:eq(1)").outerWidth();
```

But in Chrome, offset seems to return the upper left coordinates of the MAP parent, while width and height return 0.

Before I switch my approach altogether and take apart a bunch of code, is there any way to make Chrome behave like IE in this regard? (*funny, that's not a question I ever thought I'd ask lol* :))

```
<img name="index" src="index.jpg" width="3500" height="973" border="0" id="index" usemap="#m_index" alt="">
  <map name="m_index" id="m_index">
    <area shape="rect" coords="173,95,249,237" href="javascript:;" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="94,95,170,237" href="javascript:;" alt="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="12,94,88,236" href="javascript:;" alt="">
  </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a recently submitted bug report for Chrome, which seems to relate to your issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606506

In the report, it is mentioned that the area's default style,`display: inline; width: 0; height: 0`, causes the issue. 
Based on this, I tried a styling workaround by adding `display:block;` to style.
This resulted in the wrong width and zero height being returned in Chrome

```html
<area shape="rect" coords="94,95,170,237" style="display:block;" href="javascript:;" alt="">
```

```js
$("area:eq(1)").outerWidth(); //returns 280 instead of 76
$("area:eq(1)").outerHeight(); //returns 0 instead of 142
```

By adding `width` and `height` to style, it works, but might be tedious work to add specific style to each area.

It seems like there isn't a reasonable "fix" to make Chrome behave like IE, other than to wait until the bug is resolved.

**The best workaround** I can come up with in the meantime, is calculating the width and height by using the `coords` attribute:

```js
var area = $("area[shape=rect]").eq(1); //select areas with rectangle shape only
var coords = area.attr('coords').split(','); 

var x1 = coords[0],
y1 = coords[1],
x2 = coords[2],
y2 = coords[3];

var width = Math.abs(x1-x2);
var height = Math.abs(y1-y2);
```

You can use the coordinates for calculating the offset as well, and create similar workarounds for other shapes.